# Ubuntu 18.04 Audio Only Playing Through Left Side

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, audio-jack

For seemingly no reason, the audio from my right headphone has dropped from normal levels to nearly silent. However, this doesn't just seem to be an issue with the right side audio being lower than the left, as seen in pavucontrol:

[Pavucontrol Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPkSW.png)

(My account is currently unable to embed images in posts)

Alsamixer shows similar results:

[Alsamixer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbE9J.png)

Most solutions to the issue of audio imbalance seem to involve setting a lowered audio level back to the same as the normal one, but in my case I would need to lower my "normal" side because my "lowered" side never seemed to have changed volume in the first place.

This also does not seem to be an issue with my headphones, since they work fine with other devices.

Edit: After rebooting, only the right audio plays. Pulse and alsa still show that both sides should be the same.

Edit 2, 3: If it helps with anything, I ran `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` and got these results:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 128
    Memory at df220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at df200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Edit 4: Both sides of audio started working again earlier today, again for seemingly no reason. For anyone in the future looking for a solution to the same problem, the comment below recommending to check whether or not it's a hardware issue is probably the only use this post will be to you.

Comment: might be an issue in your computer hardware... improbable, but possible.

Comment: How would I go about checking that?

Comment: good question. that's tricky. :( Maybe try liveCDs of other distros? If they work, it's not the hardware, if they also have the imbalance, chances of being hardware increase...

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I have the same problem. However, it is not a problem with my hardware, since both sides work when I boot into Windows.